# How to insert and edit multi checkbox with option that user can write something in PHP script?

Tags: php, html

I created simple form to insert multiple checkbox with option that user can write in the option and the values will insert into mysql.

Here is my codes:

1. index.php

```
        <a href="add.html">+ ADD PEOPLE</a>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <table border="1">
                <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Hobby</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                include 'conn.php';
                $no = 1;
                $query = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from checkbox ");

                while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                                <td><?php echo ($data['id']); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo nl2br($data['name']); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo nl2br ($data['hobby']); ?></td>
                                <td>
                                        <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">EDIT</a>
                                        <a href="remove.php?id=<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" onclick="return checkDelete()">REMOVE</a>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                }
                ?>
        </table>
```

2. add.html

```
 <p><a href="index.php">Back</a>
 <form action="add.php" method="post">
  <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">

   <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="id" required></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" size="30" required></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
        <td width="60px" valign="top">Hobby</td>
        <td valign="top">
         <label><input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="Reading">Reading</label><br>
         <label><input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="Video Gaming">Video Gaming</label><br>
         <label><input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="other">Other</label>
                <input type="text" id="otherValue" name="other">

        </td>
       </tr>


 <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td><input type="submit" value="Save">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset"></td>
   </tr>


  </table>
 </form>
```

3. add.php

```
<?php
// connect to database
include 'conn.php';

// capture data from form
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$name = htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES);
$hobby = implode(", ", $_POST['hobby']);

// input data to database
mysqli_query($conn,"insert into checkbox(id,name,hobby) values('$id','$name','$hobby')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

// redirect page to index.php
header("location:index.php");

?>
```

4. edit.php

```
        <?php
        include 'conn.php';
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $query = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from checkbox where id='$id'");
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $datahobby=explode(', ', $data['hobby']);
                ?>
                <form method="post" action="update.php">
                        <table>
                                <tr>
                                        <td width="60px" valign="top">Hobi</td>
                                                <td valign="top">
         <label><input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="Reading" <?php if (in_array("Reading", $datahobby)) echo "checked";?> >Reading</label><br>
         <label><input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="Video Gaming" <?php if (in_array("Video Gaming", $datahobby)) echo "checked";?>  >Video Gaming</label><br>
         <label><input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="other" <?php if (in_array("other", $datahobby)) echo "checked";?>  >Other</label>
                        <input type="text" id="otherValue" name="other">
        </td>
       </tr>
                               <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td><input type="submit" value="Update">&nbsp;&nbsp;<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button></td>
                                </tr>
                        </table>
                </form>
                <?php
        }
        ?>
```

5. update.php

```
<?php
// connect to database
include 'conn.php';

// capture data from form
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$name = htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES);
$hobby = implode(",", $_POST['hobby']);

// update data ke database
mysqli_query($conn,"update checkbox set name='$name', hobby='$hobby', where id='$id'");

// redirect page to index.php
header("location:index.php");

?>
```

I have 2 problems:

1. When user input data like this:

[image: input_data]

The data displayed like this:

[image: display_data]

User input **Fishing** in the option but the data displays **other**.

I don't know how to change the script to include the Fishing value in the database.

2. When user want to edit in the option of the checkbox, the data still display **other**.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the actual value of `other` in the database in a separate field as well using the value from this input `<input type="text" id="otherValue" name="other">`.
Then while retrieving the data from the database, retrieve the `other` value, and show it on the front end (if the checkbox was checked.)

Additionally, you should be informed that using `mysqli_query` directly, you're opening yourself to sql injections. Use [mysqli prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) to avoid that.

Comment: so, you mean I must create new field in database to save value of other? OK, i will try that.

Comment: Yup. Use that value to show instead of `other` while displaying hobbies.